# Play Framework 2.4 IDE Eclipse directions don't work

Tags: eclipse, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.4

The directions can be found here:

If I try and do `activator eclipse` I get an error that eclipse isn't a command. Specifically: "[error] Not a valid command: eclipse"

If I I add `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")` to plugins.sbt it gives an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version `4.0.0` is not yet available. Use `RC2`:

`addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0-RC2")`

Edit: version `4.0.0` is now available.

Comment: `4.0.0` is available now.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the activator in command-line mode:

```
activator
```

and then enter the command to eclipsify your project:

```
eclipse
```

That worked for me.

Comment: doesn't work for me. the only way i could get it to work was to do 'activator ui' and eclipse my project there.